# Migração de iis do visual studio para iis7 local não acessa o banco

Tags: asp.net, iis

Fiz a migração do servidor IIS express padrão do vs para o IIS do meu pc.

Caminho: *visual studio >> configurações do projeto >> web >> Servidores => tirei o IIS express* e coloquei IIS local, rodou e vai até até a tela de login
mas depois da o seguinte erro "*Ocorreu um erro ao processar sua solicitação*"

Acho que ele não está conseguindo acessar o banco, alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Abra o IIS Manager (Genenciador de Serviços de Informações da Internet);
- Expanda o nó **Sites** do seu servidor. Encontre o site publicado e clique nele;
- Clique em **Error Pages** (Páginas de Erro do .NET);
- No lado direito, clique no link **Edit Configuration** (Editar Configurações de Recurso);
- Em **Mode** (Modo), selecione **Disable** (Desativar);
- Marque também a opção **Allow Nested Errors** (Permitir Erros Aninhados);
- Clique em **Ok**.

Repita o teste.

Comment: Agora deu esse erro: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

Comment: Já resolvi Tnks, resolvi indo no pool de aplicativos>>configurações avançadas>>identidade>>conta interna>>LocalSystem

Comment: Resolveu, porém você resolveu isso da forma errada, essa conta tem privilégios demais para ser usada no IIS, você nunca deveria ter que mudar a identidade do AppPool, você deveria era ter corrigido o acesso ao SQL Server, já que pela mensagem de erro era provavelmente falha no login do mesmo.

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa Era melhor ter comentado na pergunta, pro autor da pergunta ver. Por aqui ele não vai ver.

Comment: Tem razão, me esqueci de mencionar o nome dele no comentário, então @KleberBarros seria bom você ver meu comentário anterior